# How do I add a contextual menu in finder that using my mac application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

I'm trying to make a application that loads a filename (movie name) and then download the subtitle for the specific movie.

I seen a lot of mac aplications, e.g. evernote that adds things in the contextual menu in finder, I think it calls contextual menu service. In evernote's case it says "Add to evernote".

I want to accomplish with my program which should say something like "Download subtitles".

How would that be possible?

Comment: This is called a Service. You can read all about it in the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1)

Comment: I've found this: http://alexanderyolkin.com/add-app-finders-context-menu/ But haven't gotten it to work with Swift yet

Answer (score 0):

You create a service with Automator.app

Comment: Care to explain a bit more...?

Comment: Yes could you please a little bit more or point me to documents? Can I combine an automator with an app that I made? In the end I want it to be easily installed on any computer. Thanks!